# Ionic Capacitor Background Geolocation was killed on background mode. What is the best option to integrate it

Tags: android, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, capacitor

It is sending tracking data to API when the is open. but after app is in background mode, it is not sending to API. Yeah It does collect tracking data when app is in background. but only sending when the app is open again.

what is the best way to integrate realtime geo-tracking? TIA

Answer (score 0):

I use this one: https://github.com/seididieci/capacitor-backround-geolocation

It works very good, but it currently doesn't work on iOS, only Android.